# Custom dashed border.

Tags: html, css, border

[image]

I need to make something like this.

I cant use border: dotted or border: dashed, because:
1) Resulting dots and dashes not exactly the same size as in example and spacing not right either. 
2) Rounded corners with dashed/dotted borders look terrible.

Of course there is border-image, but browser support isn't great, I need IE support, at least for IE9. 
So for now I'm thinking about simply using old method with many div's and images.

What is the best way to do this, if I have many such boxes with different width and height? 
Maybe there is another way, except messing with images?

Comment: if it is a fixed height and width just use an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this as I think you indicated would be to break it up into two to three background-images.

This allows the possibility to use something like the [CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/).

Or the older method of [Sliding Doors](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/how-to-create-sliding-doors-with-css.html#fbid=iFiPhRCoDlz).

Part of the ease of use for any of these would depend upon the layout these size changing dotted boxes will be used in. For instance if you have multiple of these on a page and if so how they were output, into a grid or something else, would impact the easiest method.

Comment: Multiple backgrounds worked perfectly, thanks. Completely forgot about them, and I even manage to make them work in early versions of IE with css3pie!